# what are range-locks?

Tags: database

well,the topic introduce Isolation in wikipedia have such words,links is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control)

.........
*Serializable
This is the highest isolation level.
With a lock-based concurrency control DBMS implementation, serializability requires read and write locks (acquired on selected data) to be released at the end of the transaction. Also **range-locks** must be acquired when a SELECT query uses a ranged WHERE clause, especially to avoid the phantom reads phenomenon (see below).
When using non-lock based concurrency control, no locks are acquired; however, if the system detects a write collision among several concurrent transactions, only one of them is allowed to commit. See snapshot isolation for more details on this topic.*

but whole topic didn't explain "range-locks",google alse have no accurate description.

what's "range-locks",and which different with "read lock" and "write lock"?

thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you use a range in the `WHERE` clause the database will lock each possible tuple in this range and also the next tuple (before and after). If there is no next tuple available in a direction it will lock completely in this direction.

So the `SELECT` is reliable within the transaction.

Comment: This is not just for `BETWEEN`. Any time the selection is not for a single, unique row, you may get range locks. `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE LastName = 'Adams'` is a range, since it can return more than one row, and there is no BETWEEN clause.

Comment: It is worth noting that a range lock also locks the range between two tuples, not just the tuples themselves.

Comment: What is a "tuple" in this context?

Answer (score 23):

The easiest way to use locking (not all databases use locking at all) to prevent concurrent operations colliding, is to lock an entire database. This would make everything one-by-one though, which would be terribly slow.

Next down, is if you lock a whole table. At least other tables aren't slowed down.

Narrowest is to lock a row. You can safely update that row and not block other operations.

A range lock is in between the last two. Cases where it's used include:

1. A range of values are affected by the query.
2. A non-unique index is affected by the query (because there can be more than one row matching e.g. `23`, so `23` identifies a range rather than a row).
3. Inserting a new auto-incremented key (lock the between range `max(curvalue) + indexincrement` and `∞`).

Comment: Just a clarification to understand this better. If I run below query in a transaction w/o actually doing anything with the result-set.

SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE COL1 IN (1,2,3)

Will this cause locking of the rows selected above if range-lock is enabled ?